# Visual Studio 2010 database project is not creating a temporary database the way VS2008 used to

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

Earlier we had VS 2008 installed on local PC and SQL Express 2005 installed on local PC. When we imported a SqlServer 2005 database as a database project into VS 2008 and open the project, VS used to create an instance of the database with a GUID as its name in SQL Express. This way any schema changes I was making in the project would automatically reflect in the database created by VS2008. This was very helpful.

Currently we have VS2010 Premium and SQL Sever2008 R2 Enterprise edition installed on Windows 2003 Server. When I import a 2008 database into VS2010 database project it imports fine but does not create a temporary dev/test database automatically. Are there any settings I am missing ? If there are none, do I have to make changes and run the deployment script to the dev/test all the time ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it is what you need, but you can configure and deploy your dev/test database via Deployment page of database project. Choose "Isolated development enviroment" in combobox at the page and setup name and connection to your dev/test database. So you have two databases: "production" and "sand box" in one project.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made it clear why this temporary database was useful to you. I believe that in VS2005 it was used solely for design-time validation. This is no longer needed to support the feature.

If you need a database for test purposes, why not simply deploy one from the database project?